# How Does Argument Order Work In A Bash Shell Script?

Tags: bash

I would like to understand why these two lines of code, both work and both produce
the same content in the file created by running this shell script, in BASH.

Perhaps then I could figure out how to obtain the output I want, which is just the
file names, WITHOUT the line [[    /home/inst1/    ]] being written in there.

1st Line:

```
TargetDir=$(ls -d /home/inst1/ *.txt  *.wmv *.odt >> /home/inst1/EXEofThurs9.txt)
```

2nd Line:

```
TargetDir=$(ls -d *.txt  *.wmv *.odt /home/inst1/ >> /home/inst1/EXEofThurs9.txt)
```

File's Content :

```
Does the SubConcious Play A Role In Programming.txt  
File_Management_At_Last_2wo_YEARS_After_Beginning.odt  
/home/inst1/  
NEW_CHAT_With_FRANK_append_FILE.txt  
NewFile.txt  
rocheFlynSail.wmv  
What_Does_AYFJHS_Mean.txt
```

Comment: If you don't want `/home/inst/` in the file, why are you giving it as an argument to `ls`?

Comment: Why are you assigning the output to a variable when you're redirecting the output? There won't be any output, so this sets `TargetDir` to an empty string.

Comment: @Barmar zomg, this can happen when learning from sketchy tutorial sites all over the internet, ha.  Gotcha, thanks

Comment: It looks like you're going down the wrong path here. If you want to do something with all these files, `ls` should not be part of the solution.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me.  I tend to explore swamps a lot while learning a new area.  Just learn one tiny thing at a time and keep building and eventually get the ability to do whatever work I need to do.  Short term goal is to rip through dozens of directories and have the script write the name of every file, into a set of files established to contain only files based (of all the same) file extension.  Not to move files around, but to create those List~Files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell expands all the wildcards before executing the command. The argument order is the same as the order of the arguments that you entered; the wildcards will each be replaced by all the matching files, in lexicographic order. So when you do:

```
ls -d /home/inst1/ *.txt *.wmv *.odt
```

the shell expands each wildcard in the current directory (since the wildcards don't have directory prefixes), and the resulting command is:

```
ls -d /home/inst1 file1.txt file2.txt file1.wmf file2.wmv file3.wmv file1.odt file2.odt
```

If you're trying to expand the wildcards in the `/home/inst1` directory, you can do:

```
(cd /home/inst1; ls *.txt *.wmv *.odt >> /home/inst1/EXEofThurs9.txt)
```

Comment: So, the file was getting created by the code being executed, but the variable was empty. I see.  Hadn't tested for that, since I saw the file getting made.

Comment: If you want the output put in both the file and the variable, you can use `tee`.